# how can I use google map API for search near by places in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

Basically, I am going to build a blood donating application in which I need a search bar to show all the nearby donors data which exist in my database in case of emergency.For this purpose, I want to use the GoogleMaps API nearby places.

How can I use this in my search bar?

I just want to build like this search bar here I enter my address and as a result, this gives me all nearby donor's list from my database.

[image]

Comment: Why must the solution use Google Maps API? Why must it use Laravel? What have you tried?

Comment: @symcbean these frameworks are my client requirement. I am starting this project haven't implemented or used any other tech. If you have a better solution in terms of framework and technology please post answer here, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **haversine formula**

Below is the query using haversine formula in mysql

```
    SELECT FLOOR( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(  '30.34' ) ) * COS( RADIANS( D.lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( D.lng ) - RADIANS(  '70.35' ) ) + SIN( RADIANS(  '30.34' ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( D.lat ) ) ) ) distance
```

FROM  `donars` AS D
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 30

Order by will sort rows in ascending order.